# SiteCore Item WebAPI Remote Call failing with 403

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Hi All I am trying to call the SiteCore Item Web API remotely where
Sitecore is not installed and not able to call the service from remote machine. I am getting 403 from remote computer but getting response 200 from Sitecore machine.

Below is sample code snippet

```
   namespace SiteCoreApi
  {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create          ("http://dpc/sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=/sitecore/content/home");

        request.Headers["X-Scitemwebapi-Username"] = @"sitecore\admin";
        request.Headers["X-Scitemwebapi-Password"] = "b";

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.Write(String.Format("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength));
            Console.Write(String.Format("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType));
            // Get the stream associated with the response.
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            Console.Write("<br /> Response stream received. <br />");
            Console.Write(readStream.ReadToEnd());
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that happens because the sitecore services security policy is set by default to `ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy`, and you need to change it to `ServicesOnPolicy` you can find those configurations under :
App_Config/include/Sitecore.Services.client.config, but be careful Changing the settings in this file may impact the security of your Sitecore installation

Comment: Hi Ayman 
Thanks for your response. I am still getting the below error after doing these changes.My page url is http://dpc1/sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=/sitecore/content/home



Access to dpc1 was denied

You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

Comment: Hi Ayman I am able to access the page now .Thanks for your response. Earlier I am making changes in wrong instance..

Comment: Worked for me! Sitecore states that this setting is one of three possible settings: `ServicesOnPolicy`, `ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy`, and `ServicesOffPolicy` . This `ServicesOnPolicy` allows access to the EntityService and the ItemService. These services use Web API Action Filters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834978(v=vs.118)) to determine whether they handle or reject a request. More info here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/90/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/sitecoreservicesclient_security

Comment: This looks to be like a very good explanation of other solutions: https://laubplusco.net/implementing-webapi-service-using-servicesapicontroller-sitecore-8/